# Problems with JQuery Templates on document.load

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am sure what this really means is that I don't understand the order of events in Javascript

Can anyone explain why one of these works and the other does not?

`$(document).load()`  (does not work)
http://jsfiddle.net/KGabbert/E6SxL/3/

`$(document).ready()` (works)
http://jsfiddle.net/KGabbert/E6SxL/2/

(you should see 3 buttons on each page)

Comment: I get fickle behavior out of templates when they're not in the `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $(window).load, not $(document).load

```
$(window).load(function() {
});
```

Change that and it works.

Comment: What does document load do? Whats the difference between them?

Comment: 1. I'd appreciate an explanation for the downvote. It's true .. it fixes it. You can try in jsfiddle

Comment: 2. `window.onLoad` is a standard browser event which fires after the whole document (including images etc) has loaded. document.ready is a jquery event which fires as soon as the html is completely loaded, but potentially before images have finished loading. It's also more consistent accross browsers (apparently different browsers treat window.onLoad slightly differently)

Comment: I downvoted it because my question wasn't how to get it to work. I'm wanting to know why it doesn't. The 1st draft of my fiddle uses window.load - http://jsfiddle.net/KGabbert/E6SxL/1/   document.load() is exposed by JQuery but nothing works. I can't seem to find any explanation in documentation about document.load.  document.ready() fires when the DOM is loaded, but document.load() is advertised to fire when everything (likely except for images) is loaded (although jquery still has probs with images.Load).  so the question is: What's going on? why does it break? links to explanations work.

Comment: As far as I know, $(document).load() doesnt exist. $(window).load does exist, as does $(someelement).load() ... http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Funny, I thought I was being gently non-confrontational by not spelling out "you're doing it wrong", but giving you enough info to fix your problem. Never mind, eh. Anyway, hopefully you've got enough to go on now. Good luck.

Comment: not a problem. you likely have the right answer.  document.load may not really exist.  If someone doesn't answer with anything definitive, its yours.